# How to mute Windows with WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, volume

I am learning C# and WPF and had an idea for a little utility. I want a big red button that will do only one thing: completely mute/un-mute all Windows sounds (system beeps, WMP, DVD player, etc...) I've explored the object browser in VS 2008 but can't seem to find what I need: A mute that will affect all of Windows.

Is it `System.Windows.Input.MediaCommands.MuteVolume` and I'm just not getting how to use it?

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction using C# and/or WPF.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that command is used by the individual WPF controls for muting.  For instance, if the CommandTarget were a MediaElement, it would mute its sound when that command was executed.  Unfortunately, I think you're going to have to do a bit more work.  A quick google gave some examples for doing the p/invoke way, which is probably the only way to do it as of now in .NET:

For XP: [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/0152ff8a-0d1c-4cad-b7cd-32d18ea9975d)

For Vista/7: [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/CoreAudio.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use NAudio (http://naudio.codeplex.com/releases/view/79035). Download the latest version. Extract the DLLs  and reference the DLL NAudio in your C# project.

Then add the following code to iterate through all available audio devices and mute it if possible.

```
        try
        {
            //Instantiate an Enumerator to find audio devices
            NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator MMDE = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator();
            //Get all the devices, no matter what condition or status
            NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceCollection DevCol = MMDE.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DataFlow.All, NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DeviceState.All);
            //Loop through all devices
            foreach (NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice dev in DevCol)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Show us the human understandable name of the device
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(dev.FriendlyName);
                    //Mute it
                    dev.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Do something with exception when an audio endpoint could not be muted
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //When something happend that prevent us to iterate through the devices
        }
```